# Haskell: Data Type error by parsing

Tags: haskell

I have a string that I Need to parse to Array of Array or otherwise.

This is the Code I have

```
import Test.HUnit (runTestTT,Test(TestLabel,TestList),(~?=))
import qualified Text.Parsec as P (char,runP,noneOf,many,(<|>),eof)
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String 
import Text.Parsec.Char
import Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List.Split

newtype CSV = CSV [Row] deriving (Show,Eq)
type Row = [String]

parseCSV :: Parser CSV
parseCSV = error "not done yet"  

runParsec :: Parser a -> String -> Maybe a
runParsec parser input = case P.runP parser () "" input of
    Left  _ -> Nothing
    Right a -> Just a
```

When I start implementing parseCSV function

```
parseCSV = Just (CSV [[""]])
```

I get this error:

```
Expected type: Parser CSV
Actual type: Maybe CSV
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
parseCSV :: Parser CSV
parseCSV = return $ CSV [[""]]
```

The error says it all: `parseCSV` should have type `Parser CSV` (from the type signature), but `Just (CSV [[""]])` has type `Maybe CSV`.

Comment: it worked! I will mark it as correct answer in a few minutes, thanks!